# Parameter Estimation of Kinetic model

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, nonlinear-optimization

I have a chemical kinetic model (2-Tissue compartment Model) with Constrained K3(where K3 is rate constant)

I have modelled plasma function along with Chemical kinetic model in order to plot the output characteristics

I would  like to estimate the Rate Constant k3 from the Code below

```
function c_t = output_function_constrainedK3(t, a1, a2, a3,b1,b2,b3,td, tmax,k1,k2,k3)

DV_free= k1/(k2+k3);
K3 = k3*((k1/k2)/DV_free);
K_1   = (k1*k2)/(k2+K3);
K_2   = (k1*K3)/(k2+K3);

c_t = zeros(size(t));

ind = (t > td) & (t < tmax);

c_t(ind)= conv(((t(ind) - td) ./ (tmax - td) * (a1 + a2 + a3)),(K_1*exp(-(k2+K3)*t(ind)+K_2)),'same');

ind = (t >= tmax);

c_t(ind)= conv((a1 * exp(-b1 * (t(ind) - tmax))+ a2 * exp(-b2 * (t(ind) - tmax))) + a3 * exp(-b3 * (t(ind) - tmax)),(K_1*exp(-(k2+K3)*t(ind)+K_2)),'same');

plot(t,c_t);
figure

%plot(t,c_tnp);
axis([0 50 -2000 80000]);
xlabel time ;
ylabel concentration ;

end
```

The initial estimates for all the parameters is enlisted below

```
t=0:0.1:60;
td =0.3;
tmax=0.8;
a1=2501;
a2=18500;
a3=65000;
b1=0.5;
b2=0.7;
b3=0.3;
k1=0.014;
k2=0.051;
k3=0.07;
```

Kindly suggest me a method to estimate K3 parameter from nonlinear kinetic model code described above

In the above function the parameters values for a1, a2, a3,b1, b2 ,b3, td, tmax, k1, k2 will remain constant.

I would like to know how K3 value changes with change in time t value, for this i would like to initially estimate K3 at t interval t=0:0.1:60..

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: @denfromufa I really appreciate your response,Do you have any other idea to estimate one single parameter K3 , except K3 all parameters are will remain constant  in the above function, if you know any other process let me know, TOMLAB seems to be another software altogether, i have never used it, and quite new to relearn,and unfortunately i have very little time to finish this task..Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You can use any gradient based search algorithm. since you have one unknown, define a cost function (which can be a least square error estimation), then use a newton-raphson